# Regular Expression multiple numbers, and sequential numbers

Tags: asp.net, regex

I need regex with the following rules:

1. numeric only
2. minimum and maximum characters of 9
3. not allowed to type the same number multiple times like `1111111111`
4. no sequential numbers ascending like `1234567`
   and no sequential numbers descending like `7654321`

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: a Regex may not be your best choice for this.

Comment: @JeffreyWieder what would you suggest?  It's a asp.net application and I'm trying to validate a Telerik RadMaskedTextBox.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to put all of that into a single regex and once you've made that decision. Requirements 1, 2, 3 can be done with multiple regexes. 4 is possible with regexes, but it's probably more efficient to walk through a character at a time and perform the validation yourself.

Comment: It's possible with regex but it would be horrible. I would recommend iterating over the string(?) and do the checking yourself.

Comment: If I understand it; I suggest you to use regex -like `\d{9}` for (1) and (2)- then you need to exclude 11 special numbers -`111111111`, ... , `999999999`, `123456789`, `987654321` - ;).

Comment: @shA.t that is correct.  That's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
^
(?!
  (.)\1{8}
 )
(?!
  (?: 123456789|987654321 )
 )
\d{9}
$
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/dN9oA9/1)